# How to convert csv to json and write a specific function to generate a graph using javascript?

Tags: javascript, python, json, pandas, data-visualization

I'm trying to visualize a data by generating a graph using keylines. It takes the data in json format. 
I'm trying to convert excel data to json format. I have two columns in the excel sheet.

Start node Connecting Node

A       -     B

A      -      C

A      -      D

B      -      D

D       -     F

As there are thousands of lines of data, what kind of a function should i write so that i can generate the items in this format in javascript:

I need to first initialize the nodes and the link.

```
const data = { type: 'LinkChart',
  items: [
    { type: 'node', id: 'ac1'},
    { type: 'node', id: 'ac2'},
    { type: 'link', id: 'l1', id1: 'ac1', id2: 'ac3 },
    { type: 'link', id: 'l2', id1: 'ac1', id2: 'ac3'} 
  ]
};
```

To create a graph I need to write it in this specific way. First I have to initialize the type node and write that line for A B C D F . After that I have to write the 'link' lines.

I created a dictionary using python to convert csv into json
[{"start": "A", "connect": "B"}, {"start": "A", "connect": "C"}, {"start": "A", "connect": "D"}, {"start": "B", "connect": "C"}, {"start": "D", "connect": "F"}]

How do I write a function to take this data and write it into the items part to generate the graph. Like in the manner of first writing all the nodes then the link lines in that same pattern. I need to write in this format for 50,000+ lines.Also how can I initialize the nodes uniquely as in A is initialized as a node once not 3 times as in the data. I am new to this so i dont have much idea.

Comment: You need to provide some idea of how you intend to transform the input to the required output, along with what you have tried. E.g. the input has 5 nodes and 5 lines (or 3 lines if ABDF is counted as one line) but the *data* example only has 3 nodes and 2 lines.

Comment: Ya I did that...How can write that function? Or any specific topics I should go through and study

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this (using Python terms.  In js, substitute list with array, and dict with object)

1. Save spreadsheet to csv
2. Read csv into list (50k rows is alot but
   should still load at once, unless your data values are enormous)
3. Create empty `items` list
4. iterate over the list of data using a `map` function or a simple `for` loop
5. In this looping function, create a dict for each row, check if `items` has a dict with the current node as type (you could also make a separate list of nodes in the dict--might be faster but also use more memory)

   - if not create the dict and add to `items`
6. Create another dict for the links and add that to `items` as well (if you need to avoid duplicate links, do that check here first)
7. After the loop, add the `items` array to your `data` dict

Comment: Hi thanks, I tried creating a dictionary: 

[{"start": "A", "connect": "B"}, {"start": "A", "connect": "C"}, {"start": "A", "connect": "D"}, {"start": "B", "connect": "C"}, {"start": "D", "connect": "F"}]

I did this in python only converting csv into json. Now I just have to write this in the format of the chart items to generate the graph... I don't know how I should write that function like first defining the nodes then the links